# Operator == doesn't exists in std::vector?

Tags: c++, vector, operators

```
class Map {
private:
    std::vector<std::string> key;
    std::vector<std::string> storage;
    int i;
public:
    Map();
    Map* set(std::string, std::string);
    std::string get(std::string);
};

Map::Map() {}
Map* Map::set(std::string k, std::string v) {
    key.push_back(k);
    storage.push_back(v);
    i++;
    return (this);
}
std::string Map::get(std::string k) {
    for (int k = 0; k < i; i++)
        if (key[i] == k)
            return storage[i];
}
```

I'm still playing around with C++ and classes this time. I haven't "studied" maps and vectors yet, just read some documentation. This class serves no purpose but to try things out, so: yes, i know something similar to what I'm trying to achieve here already exists.

Why, compiling this code, am I getting:

> main.cpp:32: error: no match for 'operator==' in
>   '((Map*)this)->Map::key. std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[] [with
>   _Tp = std::basic_string, std::allocator >, _Alloc =
>   std::allocator,
>   std::allocator > >](((long unsigned int)((Map*)this)->Map::i))
>   == k'

I mean, is that for real that the == operator doesn't exists in vector?

Comment: Your iteration is wrong, its not the key[i] == k that outputs an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is shadowing. 
Your int k shadows your parameter std::string k, so the compiler sees string == int and there is no such comparator.

Answer (score 5):

You're comparing a string value in `std::vector<string> key` to an `int`. Which is not possible.

(On a side note, a `map` is generally implemented as a sorted binary tree)

Comment: generally, comparison `int` and `string` is not possible, but you can make comparison like this: `string.length` and `int` or `itoa(int)` and `string` or ... :)

Comment: @loldop Yeah I know that, but I've called the `std::string` method argument the same way as the iterator integer in the for loop. And with `k` I was referring to the argument, too bad C++ thought otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

In your `for`-loop you declare the loop-counter with the name `k` and type `int`, which hides the name of your parameter of type `std::string`.